# Songs in playlist - Apple Music

Tags: music, playlist, library

I have an apple music subscription and then decided to make some cool playlists.

But now, my library is FULL of albums that I never play outside of my playlists, an ugly ugly nightmare. I guess my question is:
**How can I have songs in playlist but not in the library?**

I don't want to see them outside of the playlist!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is - you can't.

The Library is your total structure, containing everything.
Playlists are made from the overall structure.

You can delete a song from a Playlist without removing it from the Library - but if you delete a song from the Library, it will also delete it from all Playlists.

Answer (score 1):

In the newest versions of the iTunes (tested on the 12.6.2.20), you can uncheck the box in the Settings, to *not* add songs to your library when adding them to your playlists (see screenshot with the red arrow pointing to the checkbox).

[image: itunes-no-library-checkbox]